# Does List.AddRange call List.Add?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a custom class derived from List with an Add method that adds only if a certain condition is satisfied.

Do I also need to override* AddRange, or does AddRange simply call Add on each element of the given range?

*: Yes, `new` is *hiding* and not overriding in the context of C#.

Comment: The `.Add` method on `List<T>` is not virtual so I wonder how did you override it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov using `new`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'd be doing a lot more work with no benefit.

Comment: @Superbest Does “it actually works” count as a benefit?

Comment: You would also be making this custom class far more useful. Remember that in .NET it's best to work with the highest possible class in the hierarchy, for example `IList<T>` or even `IEnumerable<T>` if you only need to be looping. By having your methods expose some custom List makes them badly coupled to your code and not reusable. By the way what's the reason for needing to write a custom collection? With LINQ that's pretty useless effort anyway.

Comment: @svick it already works.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `AddRange` calls `Add` or not. It certainly will not call your hiding `Add` but rather the hidden `Add`. And no it doesn't work. It's a huge LSP violation. And how is deriving from `Collection<T>` "a lot more work"?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I believe you are confused. The comment (as you can tell from the "@ DarinDimitrov") was in response to Darin Dimitrov, who suggested implementing `IList<T>`.

Comment: @Superbest Deriving from `Collection<T>` is a special case of implementing `IList<T>` designed to simplify your specific problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create custom collection. Don't derive it from `List<T>` but from [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) or directly implement `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`. Indeed, the `Add` method in the `List<T>` class is not virtual.

Note: `List<T>.AddRange` uses `Array.Copy`.

#### UPDATE

When inheriting Collection you just have to override 2 methods!

```
public class MyCollection : Collection<string>
{
    private bool IsValidItem(string item)
    {
        return; // Your condition : true if valid; false, otherwise.
    }

    // This method will be called when you call MyCollection.Add or MyCollection.Insert
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, string item)
    {
        if(IsValidItem(item))
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    // This method will be called when you call MyCollection[index] = newItem
    protected override void SetItem(int index, string item)
    {
        if(IsValidItem(item))
            base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

If your items to validate are not `string` replace `string` in the code above by the correct type.

Comment: Why is it relevant how is `List<T>.AddRange()` actually implemented?

Comment: @svick _List<T>_ must not be derived because its methods are not virtual contrary to _Collection<T>_. _List<T>.AddRange_ is implemented using _Array.Copy_.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That's why I'm asking why did you even mention `List<T>.AddRange()`. It wouldn't affect the result one way or another (exactly because `List<T>.Add()` isn't virtual).

Comment: `Collection<T>` is the way to go. It's designed for this very situation.

Comment: @Superbest It doesn't, since `Collection` is an **Interface**, thus does not implement anything. You'll have to implement that behavior yourself. **Edit:** I hate it, when the comments I'm answering to, simply get deleted...

Comment: @Nolonar There are [Collection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx): a class and [ICollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx): an interface

Comment: @CédricBignon Oops, I can't believe I didn't notice the missing "I". I've been working too much with interfaces lately...

Comment: So is `Collection<T>.Add` supposed to be virtual? Unless I'm mistaken it isn't.

Comment: @Superbest `Collection<T>.Add` isn't virtual, but `SetItem` and `InsertItem` are. `Collection<T>`'s public methods like `Add` forward to a few `protected virtual` methods that you should override.

Comment: @CodesInChaos so what do I need to override exactly to change the behavior of `Add`?

Comment: @Superbest Check my update to understandhow to change the behavior of _Add_.

Comment: I don't understand why it's better to override these two methods instead of `Add` (other than that the authors of `Collection` declared that they want me to using `virtual`). Does anything other than `Add` call `SetItem` or `InsertItem`? What if I want to be able to insert items without validation using `InsertItem` and with validation using `Add`?

Comment: @Superbest You can't override _Add_ because _Add_ is not virtual, you can only hide it.

Comment: There are several ways to modify an `IList<T>`. `Add`, `Insert`, the indexer (`list[i]=x`). All of these should be consistent. "What if I want to be able to insert items without validation using `InsertItem` and with validation using `Add`?" if you want such bad design, inherit from `IList<T>` yourself. The framework authors didn't go out of their way to make it easier to do dumb stuff.

Comment: While I appreciate the subtleties of hiding vs. overriding, in my application this is irrelevant. I am certain that my custom collection will never be cast or inherited from. It just seems weird to reimplement two methods when I could do with just one.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use hiding that changes the semantics of the method. That's really bad design.

Create a new class that implements `IList<T>`. The easiest way to do that is inheriting from `Collection<T>`. `Collection<T>` implements `IList<T>` and has four extension points in the form of `protected virtual` methods:

```
InsertItem
SetItem
RemoveItem
ClearItems
```

Since you only needs to validate items that get added and not those that get removed, you only need to override `InsertItem` and `SetItem`.

```
class MyCollection:Collection<T>
{
    private void ValidateItem(T item)
    {
       if(item is invalid)
         throw new ArgumentException("Item is invalid");
    }

    protected override InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        ValidateItem(item);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        ValidateItem(item);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: "That's really bad design." - Why?

Comment: @Superbest Because casting to the base class circumvents your hiding.

Comment: Violates LSP, you don't have a consistent implementation anymore (`IList<T>.Add`, `List<T>.Add`, `MyList.Add` aren't consistent), etc.

Comment: Don't things like circle-ellipse violate LSP anyway?

Comment: @Superbest: yes. So do a lot of other things. What's your point?

Comment: @siride I believe my point was that "violates LSP" is not necessarily a reason to not do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a collection that behaves exactly like a `List<T>`, except for adding only valid objects, I wouldn't create a custom collection.

Use **Extensions** instead and call them `AddIfValid(T value)` and `AddRangeIfValid(IEnumerable<T>)` or whatever you like, as long as it's clear what the Extension is doing.

Here's an example:

```
public static void AddIfValid(this List<T> list, T value)
{
    if (/* check if value is valid here */)
        list.Add(value);
}
```

Once you have defined your Extension, use it like this:

```
myList.AddIfValid(myValue);
```